# Sort multiple columns' values from min to max, and put in new columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with datetime objects in columns 3 through 6. I want to sort these dates into new columns: `P_min`, `P_2`, `P_3`, `P_max`, from earliest ("min") to latest date ("max"). I can easily get the min and max values and put them into their own column. However, how can I get the middle values (`P_2` and `P_3`)?

This is what I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['a','b','c','d'],'Number':[1,2,3,4], 'Contact':['foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4'],3:[pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015'),pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015')],4:[pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002')], 5:[pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('3/15/2015')], 6:[pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('3/15/2015'),pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('4/10/2007')]}); 
> df

   Name NumberContact   3           4           5          6
0   a   1   foo1        2015-01-01  2002-02-20  NaT        NaT
1   b   2   foo2        NaT         2002-02-20  NaT        2015-03-15
2   c   3   foo3        NaT         2002-02-20  NaT        NaT
3   d   4   foo4        2015-01-01  2002-02-20  2015-03-15 2007-04-10
```

Then I can manually set the min and max values:

```
df['P_min'] = df.iloc[:,3:6].min(axis=1) #axis=1 is the column
df['P_max'] = df.iloc[:,3:6].max(axis=1) #axis=1 is the column
```

I'm trying to make something work where I replace the min/max values so I could get a new min value which would be P_2, and so forth...

```
df.iloc[:,3:7].replace(to_replace=df.iloc[:,3:7].min(axis=1), value=pd.NaT)
```

Could someone please help with a more efficient or easy method such as a for loop?

Comment: Does `np.sort(df.iloc[:,3:6], axis=1)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is elegant solution with convertation to numpy matrix of int -> sort -> convert it back to datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['a','b','c','d'],'Number':[1,2,3,4], 'Contact':['foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4'],3:[pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015'),pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015')],4:[pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002')], 5:[pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('3/15/2015')], 6:[pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('3/15/2015'),pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('4/10/2007')]}); 

matrix = np.array(df[df.columns[3:7]].astype(int))
matrix.sort(axis = 1)


df_t = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns = ['P_min', 'P_2', 'P_3', 'P_max'])
conc = [pd.to_datetime(df_t[x]) for x in df_t.columns]

pd.concat([df] + conc, axis = 1)

Out[1]:
        Name    Number  Contact         3            4          5           6           P_min           P_2         P_3         P_max
    0   a         1       foo1    2015-01-01        2002-02-20  NaT         NaT          NaT            NaT        2002-02-20   2015-01-01
    1   b         2       foo2     NaT              2002-02-20  NaT        2015-03-15    NaT            NaT        2002-02-20   2015-03-15
    2   c         3       foo3     NaT              2002-02-20  NaT         NaT          NaT            NaT         NaT         2002-02-20
    3   d         4       foo4    2015-01-01        2002-02-20  2015-03-15  2007-04-10  2002-02-20  2007-04-10     2015-01-01   2015-03-15
```

### Tricky way how to normalize all P_min to real date, to avoid NaT

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['a','b','c','d'],'Number':[1,2,3,4], 'Contact':['foo1','foo2','foo3','foo4'],3:[pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015'),pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015')],4:[pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002'),pd.to_datetime('2/20/2002')], 5:[pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('3/15/2015')], 6:[pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('3/15/2015'),pd.NaT,pd.to_datetime('4/10/2007')]}); 

matrix = np.array(df[df.columns[3:7]].astype(int))

matrix[matrix == -9223372036854775808] = 4102444800000000000   # it gives you 2100-01-01 after convertation, you can easily filtered it out then
matrix.sort(axis = 1)

df_t = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns = ['P_min', 'P_2', 'P_3', 'P_max'])
conc = [pd.to_datetime(df_t[x]) for x in df_t.columns]
pd.concat([df] + conc, axis = 1)

Out[2]:
Name    Number    Contact        3            4           5             6          P_min        P_2         P_3         P_max
0       a   1   foo1       2015-01-01   2002-02-20  NaT          NaT           2002-02-20   2015-01-01  2100-01-01  2100-01-01
1       b   2   foo2       NaT          2002-02-20  NaT          2015-03-15    2002-02-20   2015-03-15  2100-01-01  2100-01-01
2       c   3   foo3       NaT          2002-02-20  NaT          NaT           2002-02-20   2100-01-01  2100-01-01  2100-01-01
3       d   4   foo4       2015-01-01   2002-02-20  2015-03-15   2007-04-10    2002-02-20   2007-04-10  2015-01-01  2015-03-15
```

Comment: Hi, same comment as above: Is there an easy way to make sure that all the rows have a `P_min` value as opposed to all having `P_max` values? Like, I imagine that the sort would start from `P_min` rather than filling backwards from `P_max`. Thank you!

Comment: May be i don't understand your questions. But we explicitly put all columns from P_min to P_max for all rows. So yes. They all have it. But some of the P_min has value =  NaT

Comment: The way I was envisioning the final dataframe would be for all rows in the P_min column to be filled with values (none should have NaT), but I can try to work around this.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what  -9223372036854775808 and 4102444800000000000 are in the code?

Comment: I know, looks a little bit tricky :)

np.array(df[df.columns[3:7]].astype(int)) - it gives you matrix with int.  And all pd.NaT become  -9223372036854775808. 
When you sort matrix by axis = 1 all such values move to left of matrix. 

To avoid this, we would change all this constant to any big integer that convertation to date would be known and big enought (4102444800000000000 - is a Timestamp('2100-01-01 00:00:00'))

And after this when you sort matrix all such values move to right. That's it )

Comment: Huh. That's an interesting way to go about it. The only thing I would add is to replace the artificial 2100-01-01 values with NaT at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

- [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) as pointed out by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang)
- [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with parameters `axis=1` and `result_tupe='expand'`

```py
import pandas as pd

print(df)  # from your data

Name  Number Contact          3          4          5          6
   a       1    foo1 2015-01-01 2002-02-20        NaT        NaT
   b       2    foo2        NaT 2002-02-20        NaT 2015-03-15
   c       3    foo3        NaT 2002-02-20        NaT        NaT
   d       4    foo4 2015-01-01 2002-02-20 2015-03-15 2007-04-10

# create new columns
df[['P_min', 'P_2', 'P_3', 'P_max']] = df.iloc[:, 3:7].apply(lambda x: np.sort(x), axis=1, result_type='expand')

# Updated dataframe
Name  Number Contact          3          4          5          6      P_min        P_2        P_3      P_max
   a       1    foo1 2015-01-01 2002-02-20        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT 2002-02-20 2015-01-01
   b       2    foo2        NaT 2002-02-20        NaT 2015-03-15        NaT        NaT 2002-02-20 2015-03-15
   c       3    foo3        NaT 2002-02-20        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT        NaT 2002-02-20
   d       4    foo4 2015-01-01 2002-02-20 2015-03-15 2007-04-10 2002-02-20 2007-04-10 2015-01-01 2015-03-15
```

Comment: Just a quick adjustment: Is there an easy way to make sure that all the rows have a `P_min` value as opposed to all having `P_max` values? Like, I imagine that the sort would start from `P_min` rather than filling backwards from `P_max`. Thank you!

Comment: @JAG2024 not easily.  You would probably have to write a custom function to reorder the information based on how many are `NaT`.

Comment: Hmm, tricky. Maybe I'll give it a shot and ask another question on S.O. Thanks for  the help.

Comment: It's kind of janky, but I can sort the new dataframe with this: df[::-1], and it does what I need to do.